# Unexpect token '(' on multiple expression statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Was trying to do a mutliple expression if statement as shown on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) but my browser seems to throw a error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (` The second if statement is the one in question: `if ( newbalance > 0 || newincome > 0 ) || ( newbalance > 0 && newincome > 0 ) {`

Full function

```
    // Start inverval
    function ticker(p) {

        var newbalance = 0;
        var newincome = 0;

        if ( p == true ) {

            if ( newbalance > 0 || newincome > 0 ) || ( newbalance > 0 && newincome > 0 ) {
                newbalance = ( newbalance + 1 );
            } else {
                newbalance = ( rmoney.balance + 1 );
            }

            $('.balancec').html('$' + formatMoney(newbalance, 2));

        } else {

            if ( btrigger.taxhike ) {
                var ticker = setTimeout(function(){
                    if ( newbalance > 0 && newincome > 0 ) {
                        newbalance = ( newbalance + boosts.taxhike ),
                        newincome = ( newincome + boosts.taxhike );
                    } else {
                        newbalance = ( newbalance + boosts.taxhike ),
                        newincome = ( newincome + boosts.taxhike );
                    }
                    $('.balancec').html('$' + formatMoney(newbalance, 2));
                    $('.incomec').html('+$' + formatMoney(newincome, 2) + '/ps');

                });
            }
            if ( btrigger.raisepay ) {
                var ticker = setTimeout(function(){
                    if ( newbalance > 0 && newincome > 0 ) {
                        newbalance = ( newbalance + boosts.raisepay ),
                        newincome = ( newincome + boosts.raisepay );
                    } else {
                        newbalance = ( newbalance + boosts.raisepay ),
                        newincome = ( newincome + boosts.raisepay );
                    }
                    $('.balancec').html('$' + formatMoney(newbalance, 2));
                    $('.incomec').html('+$' + formatMoney(newincome, 2) + '/ps');
                });
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing parenthesis here,

```
if (( newbalance > 0 || newincome > 0 ) || ( newbalance > 0 && newincome > 0 )){
---^  ------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

The basic syntax for the if statement is,

```
if(condition){
  code block
}
```

But you have used a syntax which is some thing like

```
if condition {
  code block
}
```

Comment: Lol drat! That's how I had it before thinking PHP. Thank you!

Comment: @JordanThompson It happens to everyone, when we handle multiple programming language.. :) glad to help.!

Answer (score 1):

You do **not** have opening `(` and closing `)` parenthesis for `if` statement, You have `if()()` instead of `if(()())` the outer set is missing.

Change

```
if ( newbalance > 0 || newincome > 0 ) || ( newbalance > 0 && newincome > 0 ) {
```

To

```
if (( newbalance > 0 || newincome > 0 ) || ( newbalance > 0 && newincome > 0 ) ){
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing open and closed parenthesis

```
if ( (newbalance > 0 || newincome > 0 ) || ( newbalance > 0 && newincome > 0 )) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Start inverval
function ticker(p) {

  var newbalance = 0;
  var newincome = 0;

  if ( p == true ) {

    if (( newbalance > 0 || newincome > 0 ) || ( newbalance > 0 && newincome > 0 ) {
      newbalance = ( newbalance + 1 );
    } else {
      newbalance = ( rmoney.balance + 1 );
    }

    $('.balancec').html('$' + formatMoney(newbalance, 2));

  } else {

    if ( btrigger.taxhike ) {
      var ticker = setTimeout(function(){
        if ( newbalance > 0 && newincome > 0 ) {
          newbalance = ( newbalance + boosts.taxhike ),
            newincome = ( newincome + boosts.taxhike );
        } else {
          newbalance = ( newbalance + boosts.taxhike ),
            newincome = ( newincome + boosts.taxhike );
        }
        $('.balancec').html('$' + formatMoney(newbalance, 2));
        $('.incomec').html('+$' + formatMoney(newincome, 2) + '/ps');

      });
    }
    if ( btrigger.raisepay ) {
      var ticker = setTimeout(function(){
        if ( newbalance > 0 && newincome > 0 ) {
          newbalance = ( newbalance + boosts.raisepay ),
            newincome = ( newincome + boosts.raisepay );
        } else {
          newbalance = ( newbalance + boosts.raisepay ),
            newincome = ( newincome + boosts.raisepay );
        }
        $('.balancec').html('$' + formatMoney(newbalance, 2));
        $('.incomec').html('+$' + formatMoney(newincome, 2) + '/ps');
      });
    }

  }

}
```

use this you miss "(" in your code

Answer (score 1):

it seems your function is correct but you ended if condition

```
       if ( newbalance > 0 || newincome > 0 ) || ( newbalance > 0 && newincome > 0 ) {

}
```

you need change your  if condition to ..

```
    if (( newbalance > 0 || newincome > 0 ) || ( newbalance > 0 && newincome > 0 )){
}
```

**How to use logical oprator**

for e.g

Given that x=6 and y=3, the table below explains the logical operators:

```
Operator      Description                                Example
&&                and                         (x < 10 && y > 1) is true
||                or                          (x==5 || y==5) is false
!                 not                         !(x==y) is true
```